# Override Grails scaffolding URLs entirely or with prefix

Tags: grails, scaffolding

I have a controller that has `static scaffold = true` defined, as well as some custom actions.

I would like to ensure that only logged-in users and those of type ADMIN (some `Enum` value in our domain) can access it. To achieve this I've implemented a grails filter that is mapped to the `/admin/**` URI space, but of course the URIs for the Domain/Controller in question when scaffolding are not under there. I have added custom, named, URL mappings for the show/edit/create actions (which work and delegate straight to the scaffold layer), but I end up with two URI contexts dedicated to this purpose.

I would prefer being able to say to the scaffolded controller "Use this URI as a prefix for all your URIs" and be done with it, but searching the docs and web in general have not proven very helpful.

Any ideas?

Comment: you want that /admin/something point to your scaffolded controller, even if the name of controller is other? Can you provide a example of url to clarify?

Comment: No - I want my /admin/ URLs to be the dedicated URLs for a given controller. Everything else can use the default scheme. Answer below :)

Comment: I have implemented Spring security in my solution which allows me to control which users have access to uris, I would think it maybe applicable in your case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Scaffolded controllers generate all their URLs using the standard taglib calls, which are sensitive to URL mappings.  So if you have the URL mappings right then it should just work.  If you have a `MyDomainController` that you want to be mapped under `/admin` then you need something like

```
class UrlMappings {
  static mappings = {
    "/$controller/$action?/$id?" {
      constraints {
        controller(validator:{
          // make sure this mapping doesn't apply to the MyDomainController,
          // so it will only be accessible via the protected /admin URL
          return it != "myDomain"
        })
      }
    }

    // special rule for the MyDomainController
    "/admin/myDomain/$action?/$id?"(controller:"myDomain")
  }
}
```

You can use [any of the usual Grails constraint types](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#applyingConstraints) on a URL mapping, so you could restrict by whitelist

```
controller(inList:['foo', 'bar'])
```

or by regular expression

```
// exclude all controllers whose name starts "sec", e.g. secUser, secRole, ...
controller(matches:/(?!sec).*/)
```

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks! The validator `!= "myDomain"` is what did it - the rest of the mappings just "worked". Any ideas where I can read about how this works?

Comment: @atc http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#applyingConstraints is the relevant bit of the user guide.  Essentially, you can apply constraints to variables bound by a URL mapping in exactly the same way as you can to domain or command object properties.